# How do I install curl with ares enabled

Tags: curl

I have curl installed and that works fine, however I've been reading about the blocking nature of the DNS lookups and discovered that it's slowing down my app.

I've done apt-get install libc-ares2 but I'm not sure how to tell curl to use that library when doing a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the libcurl library must be built with c-ares support at compile time. From a cursory glance at the curl [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl) This doesn't appear to be a dependancy of libcurl under Ubuntu, so it looks like you are left compiling and statically linking to your build of the libcurl library. This seems like a more appropriate question for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Okay I'll ask it over there (unless there is an easy way to move it over?)

Comment: Not that I know of, and if there is, it probably requires more rep.